# Regexp in Javascript: replace minus with comma+minus when condition is met

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace `\-` minus with `\,+-` comma+minus when space/no-space/comma before the minus. In a SVG path I found this:

```
`201.86-38.778`
```

and I need to make it

```
`201.86,-38.778`.
```

I tried `str.replace(/-/g,'\,-')` but this creates additional commas when not needed.

**Update**, I also need this to work like this:

```
`201.86 -38.778` // notice the space
```

to make it

```
`201.86,-38.778`.
```

Comment: I don't know how to only replace the minus in only this case. I tried `str.replace(/-/g,'\,-')` but this creates additional commas when not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/(^|[^,\s])-/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK1lX8/1)

Breakdown:

- `(^|[^,\s])` - match and capture the start of string or a character other than a comma or whitespace (that will be referenced to with the `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern)
- `-` - a literal hyphen.

In the replacement pattern, use `$1,-`, a backreference to the captured text + comma and a hyphen.

Demo:

```js
var re = /(^|[^,\s])-/g; 
var str = '201.86-38.778';
var result = str.replace(re, '$1,-');
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Awesome as always.

Answer (score 1):

Find with `([-+])` and replace with `,\1`. <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bG3nG2/1)**</kbd>